# Is there a Linux equivalent of Yousendit?

Tags: linux, files

We want to get functionality similar to Yousendit or one of the other services that allows end users to upload large files. But we have a few Linux servers and want to use these instead of a third parties.

There seems to be software for practically everything else for Linux, I can't believe there isn't something that will meet our needs.

Answer (score 4):

I had a similar requirement in my company, solved it with this:
http://openupload.sourceforge.net/

It's exactly like yousendit, you upload the file, it's got even the progress indicator, and you can send an email, even with a pwd to type in to download the file. It's brilliant!

Just one thing: remember to turn off output_buffering by adding this to your .htaccess:

```
php_value output_buffering off
```

If you don't do it, every download will require as much php memory as the file size (which can easily cripple your server or will result in a 500 error).

Hope this helps :)

Max

Answer (score 3):

Do you really need a Web interface?

Externally: a public Web server serving a directory accessible by a CIFS share, which users can e-Mail out.  BasicAuth configuration for password protection, if necessary.  Client side tools for encryption.  Tons of options here in general.

Internally: wiki and general file sharing solutions such as NFS and SAMBA.  Again, tons of options.

Have you looked through [Freshmeat](http://freshmeat.net/) and [Sourceforge](http://sourceforge.net/)?

Comment: Sorry, we do need a web front end. The client will want something that looks swish and also won't want to have to do anything complicated on each end users' machine.

We don't want to be limited by email file constraints so that's not an option either.

Ideally it'd be open source so we can customise it if need be. But we don't mind paying for it.

Comment: @user39234, you should edit your question to add the extra details, as others may not read comments before answering.

Comment: John provides good advice.  I have no intent to further contribute to this and I'd have already deleted my answer had your comment not clarified the initial question.

Answer (score 2):

I've used a rebranded sendthisfile.com for a while and it worked great, but my use is sporadic and I couldn't justify paying for it when I run my own servers. I just installed and configured [Droopy](http://stackp.online.fr/?p=28) on Ubuntu 12.04. It uses Python. It seems pretty solid.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't mind spending money, I've (easily) branded/integrated a YouSendIt "corporate" account within a Website I was doing contract work for: we embedded the YouSendit form into a page on the site; took all of 15 minutes maybe.

You can customize the email message, logo, etc. they charge based on how many uploads you do per month and how much data if I recall correctly, but it wasn't much.

http://drop.io is really slick and free up to 100MB in file size; may also have an embedding/customizing option.

Answer (score 0):

http://www.popscript.com has one, but it's $139 USD, and no idea how well it works either.

Answer (score 0):

http://fex.rus.uni-stuttgart.de/

http://packages.debian.org/sid/fex

HTH

Answer (score 0):

Isn't dropbox what you need? https://www.dropbox.com/downloading

Answer (score -1):

Apache has a tendency to use as much memory per process as the uploaded file is in size. That will kill your server very soon if you continuously receive large files.

Have you tried to setup [lighttpd](http://lighttpd.net/) for your upload receiving needs? It should behave in a more sane manner: saving chunks to a temporary directory you define and not consuming all the RAM you have.

Comment: Apache was not mentioned in the question (and the tendency depends totally on the script/method used to receive uploads, apache itself can stream perfectly fine).